# Using XQuery to create valid Latex file based on XML data

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, latex, xquery

I know this task is somewhat unorthodox, but I hope someone is able to help me. I'm trying to create a valid Latex file using XQuery, based on XML file on products. The XML file (xml/products.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <Maker name = "A">
        <PC model = "1001" price = "2114">
            <Speed> 2.66 </Speed>
            <RAM> 1024 </RAM>
            <HardDisk> 250 </HardDisk>
        </PC>
```

This is the latex output I need:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
Price & Model \\ \hline
price value & model value \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And I've created the following (character escaping) XQuery to produce the required Latex:

```
let $oc := "&#123;" (: for { :)
let $cc := "&#125;" (: for } :)
let $space := "&#32;" (: space :)
let $tab := "&#9;" (: tab :)
let $ampersand := "&#38;" (: ampersand :)

\\documentclass\[\]{$oc}article{$cc}

\\begin{$oc}document{$cc}

\\begin{$oc}center{$cc}
    \\begin{$oc}tabular{$cc}{$oc}| l | l |{$cc}
    \\hline
    Model{$ampersand}Price{$space}\\\\{$space}\\hline
    {for $pc in doc("xml/products.xml")/Products/Maker/PC
let $price:=data($pc/@price)
let $model:=data($pc/@model)
return
{$model}{$ampersand}{$price} \\\\ \\hline
}
\\end{$oc}tabular{$cc}
\\end{$oc}center{$cc}

\\end{$oc}document{$cc}
```

I can't get the query to work.. :(. And as usual, XQuery does not give much debug info to go on. Are there smarter ways of escaping characters using XQuery? Or perhaps just printing text directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restructured the concat from Christian's approach a bit, and now it works. Below the code:

```
    declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
    declare option output:method "text";

    let $stringa:=string("
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l |} \hline
    Model &amp; Price \\ \hline
    ")

    return ($stringa),
        (
        for $pc in doc("xml/products.xml")/Products/Maker/PC
        let $price := data($pc/@price)
        let $model := data($pc/@model)

        return concat($model, " &amp; ", $price, " \\ \hline")
        ),
    (
    string("
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center} 
    \end{document}
    ")
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "text";

concat("\documentclass[]{ article }

\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
Price &amp; Model \\ \hline
",
for $pc in doc("xml/products.xml")/Products/Maker/PC
let $price := data($pc/@price)
let $model := data($pc/@model)
return concat($model, " &amp; ", $price, " \\ \hline
"),

"\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}")
```

Note that you may need to further modify the data returned from `products.xml` in order to make it conformant with the LateX syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, the concat() function does not seem to accept that many arguments. Any clue on splitting it into smaller pieces?

Comment: Regarding to the XQuery specification, the number of arguments for the concat() function is not limited. Which XQuery processor are you using? I have run the query with BaseX.

Comment: I am using Altova XMLSpy. Just tried it with BaseX, and that seems to deal with the concat issue. However, now it's nagging about a problem with the nested concat line (as if the nested concat can only return a single line, not a bunch caused by iteration of the return):
    Error:
    Stopped at line 19, column 16: [XPTY0004] Single item expected,      ("1001 &amp; 2114 \\ \hline", "1002 &amp; 995 \\ \hline", ...) found.

Comment: Ok got it! I restructured the concat a bit, and now it works! Thanks for your help!